# Why is PHImageRequestOptions.progressHandler called after download?

Tags: ios, swift

When I download pictures on iCloud, why do I execute this method after the download is complete?

```
@objc static func getAssetOrigin(asset:PHAsset,dealImageSuccess:@escaping (UIImage?,[AnyHashable:Any]?) -> (),dealImageFailed:@escaping () -> ()) -> Void {
         let manager = PHImageManager.default()
         let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
         option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true  
         option.resizeMode   = .fast
         option.isSynchronous = true
         option.progressHandler = {
             (progress, error, stop, info) in
             DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                 print(progress)
                 if (error != nil) {
                     dealImageFailed()
                 }
             })
         }

         manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option) { (originImage, info) in
             dealImageSuccess(originImage,info)
         }
     }
```

Comment: It might be because `option.isSynchronous` is true. Try setting that to false

Comment: Why is this a surprise? 100% is a progress amount and must be reported.

Comment: You are seeing the progress update after the completion because (a) you are performing synchronous request and (b) you are dispatching the progress update code asynchronously.

Comment: Needless to say, I would avoid making the request synchronous (and if you insist on making it synchronous, make sure you don’t do that from the main thread).